# Setting translations for WordPress Gutenberg Block in Plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm creating some new blocks for a customer, I can seem to add the translations to them, I've created a plugin and it has two blocks:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:       Cinc Blocks
 * Description:       Gutenberg blocks for Documents
 * Requires at least: 6.1
 * Requires PHP:      7.0
 * Version:           0.1.0
 * Author:            Utrans
 * License:           GPL-2.0-or-later
 * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Text Domain:       cinc-blocks
 *
 * @package           create-block
 */

/**
 * Registers the block using the metadata loaded from the `block.json` file.
 * Behind the scenes, it registers also all assets so they can be enqueued
 * through the block editor in the corresponding context.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/
 */
function cinc_blocks_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build/document' );
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build/newsletter-form' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cinc_blocks_block_init' );


function cinc_blocks_textdomain() {
    wp_set_script_translations( 'cinc-blocks-script', 'cinc-blocks', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cinc_blocks_textdomain');
```

The blocks had been created using the WordPress Create Block script, and for the translation I've followed the steps in [this page](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/docs/how-to-guides/internationalization.md)

I have a languages folder inside the plugin with the .pot file, the .po for each language and the json files with names like:

```
cinc-blocks-ca-7a039d9efb85b4d2c5e669ea35fd6e44.json
```

After all this if I check, the wp_set_script_translations always returns false, I don't know what I'm missing

Comment: What is the path to the languages folder? Do you have a separate language folder in for each the blocks? The path in `wp_set_script_translations()` not being correct could be why its returning false.

Comment: Also, if you change `'cinc-blocks'` to `'cincblocks'`  in `wp_set_script_translations()` does it work?